# Убрать ресайз хэдера при скролле при адаптации

Tags: css3, html5, responsive

Делаю сайт. Там реализовываю ресайз хэдера при скроле данны скриптом

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
     if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){
       $('.header-container').addClass("scroll-class");
     }else{
      $('.header-container').removeClass("scroll-class");
     }
    });
```

Возник вопрос. Как при переходе на мобильную версию, отключать этот скрипт? Если есть какая-то русскоязычная инфа - ткните ссылку, пожалуйста, попытаюсь сам разобраться.

Comment: зависит от того, что в вашем понимании "мобильная версия". Оберните условие в другое условие которое будет это отражать (обычно это проверка на размер окан `$(window).width() < 768` или на наличие тач ивента `'ontouchstart' in window || 'onmsgesturechange' in window`, или другие условия)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже упоминали в комментарии здесь может быть несколько вариантов.

1) использование media query:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
.scroll-class {
 // определение стилей включаемого класса
}
}
```

2) Использование javascript кода, который определяет ширину экрана и/или тип девайса.

Есть ещё более экзотические варианты, но для данной задачи это будет оверхедом.